# PHP RecursiveArrayIterator class get key-value pair recursive

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I tried to wrote a custom array iterator with PHP's factory class. My problem: I need all array's all datas, example, here is a simple PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [authentication] => Array
        (
            [basic] => Array
                (
                    [username] => guest
                    [password] => guest
                )

            [filters] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 100
                    [owener] => me
                )

        )

)
```

I see on PHP's doc page, I can use two simple class and iterate with simple foreach:

```
    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($this->phpArray));
    foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
        $d = $iterator->getDepth();
        echo "depth: $d $key => $value\n";
    }
```

This program throw following output:

```
depth: 2 key: username, value: guest
depth: 2 key: password, value: guest
depth: 2 key: price, value: 100
depth: 2 key: owener, value: me
```

How to modify my code what can do a following example output with all datas:

```
depth: 0 key: authentication, value:
depth: 1 key: basic, value:
depth: 1 key: filters, 
depth: 2 key: username, value: guest
depth: 2 key: password, value: guest
depth: 2 key: price, value: 100
depth: 2 key: owener, value: me
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) you can set different modes of traversing. The default one is `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY`. That's why you get only leaves, but not all values (by the way [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) has the same behavior). To visit all elements you need to set the mode to `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`:

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80121da49d7834c3a047fec4b40609d7163f7fed).

Comment: @Gábor, you are welcome. Iterators indeed badly documented, and it is hard to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a recursive function like this:

```
function traverseArray($arr, &$depthArray, $depth = 0){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $depthArray[$depth][] = array('depth' => $depth, 'key' => $key, 'value' => '');
            traverseArray($value, $depthArray, ++$depth);
            --$depth;
        }else{
            $depthArray[$depth][] = array('depth' => $depth, 'key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Create an empty array named `$depthArray` and call this function with two arguments, first one would be your original array `$this->phpArray` and second one would be this `$depthArray`, like this:

```
$depthArray = array();
traverseArray($this->phpArray, $depthArray);
```

Finally, use nested `foreach` loops to traverse `$depthArray` and display *key*, *value* and the associated *depth* of that element, like this:

```
foreach($depthArray as $depth => $arr){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        echo 'depth:' . $a['depth'] . ' key: ' . $a['key'] . ' value: ' . $a['value'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```